# Can't trim the string in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a string `IN-123456`; now I need to trim the `IN-` from that string. I tried as in Oracle

```
select trim('IN-' from 'IN-123456) from dual;
```

but I get an error

```
ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character
30001. 00000 -  "trim set should have only one character"
*Cause:    Trim set contains more or less than 1 character. This is not
           allowed in TRIM function.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple replace wouldn't do the trick?

```
select replace('IN-123456', 'IN-', '') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the result...

It can be solved with LTRIM() function

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, TRIM is not the correct function for the job.  You need to [REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) the (sub)string `IN-` with nothing:

```
SELECT REPLACE('IN-123456', 'IN-') FROM dual;
```

Be aware that this will replace all occurrences of `IN-` anywhere in the string.  If that's not appropriate, but the `IN-` will always be at the start of the string, then you could use [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('IN-123456', 4) FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

you just forget to complete single quote

```
select trim('IN-' from 'IN-123456') from dual;
```

now try this

Comment: Hi Gomzy, run with this code will get error in oracle,with using TRIM you can only trim a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Trim Function is always remove one char from string

Here is the example -
SELECT TRIM(both 'P' FROM 'PHELLO WORLDP') FROM DUAL

Out put -HELLO WORLD

You may use LEADING /TRAILING insert of Both.
In your case "IN-" holding three char.